# Seaborn gives wrong values on x-axis ticks?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

In the code below Matplotlib gives the correct range of 5.0 to 10.0, why is Seaborn different?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import ticker

sns.set()

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)

x = np.linspace(5, 10)
y = x ** 2

sns.barplot(x, y, ax=ax1)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(5))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))

ax2.bar(x, y, width = 0.1)
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(5))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `pointplot` instead of `scatterplot`?

Comment: @HS-nebula I just wanted a scatter with connecting lines. I thought pointplot should behave similarly to scatterplot

Comment: @HS-nebula It does seem Seaborn has correct axis ticks though if I use lineplot or scatterplot, so I guess my question is now why are pointplot and barplot different? I'm not sure what the equivalent of pointplot is in Matplotlib, but bar plot ticks are right in Matplotlib and wrong in Seaborn

Comment: There are some arguments you can provide to scatter plot to get connecting lines - `sns.scatterplot(x, y,marker='o', linestyle='dashed', ax=ax1)`

Comment: Okay I guess I didn't really understand the difference between the purpose of scatter and pointplot. I could use a scatterplot here, but this is a simplified example for stackoverflow. In my project I'm overlaying two pointplots (which I just changed to scatterplots) and 1 barplot, and still having the same issue because it happens on barplots too. So I'm trying to understand why the tick formatters don't work on Seaborn pointplot and barplot

Comment: As per [official docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html#seaborn.pointplot), a point plot represents an estimate of central tendency for a numeric variable by the position of scatter plot points and provides some indication of the uncertainty around that estimate using error bars. There is some estimation going on under the hood but since you just want a scatter plot, you are better off with `scatterplot()`

Comment: You can also use `sns.lineplot(x, y, linestyle='-', marker='o', markersize=4, ax=ax1)` if you want both lines and scatter points

Comment: @Sheldore Thanks. "an estimate of central tendency for a numeric variable by the position of scatter plot points" is pretty much what I'm doing. I'm binning a value and making a barplot of counts with a lineplot of the means. So since I only have 1 y-value per x-value I assumed pointplot/scatterplot should be same. I did try substituting it for lineplot, but since I'm using it on a twinx with a bar (which has the same problem) it doesn't help. And I want to understand why tick formatting doesn't work on barplot and pointplot even if I can substitute them here, I might need them later

Comment: Since `pointplot` and `scatterplot` aren't the same thing, please update your code and example accordingly. When I run the example code for a `barplot` and `pointplot`, both plots have the same xticklabels.

Comment: @HS-nebula Okay I updated the post to exclude pointplot since there is no pointplot in Matplotlib to compare to

Comment: This is an interesting observation, I think it might have to do with `seaborn.barplot` expecting categorical variables for x (i.e. discrete), whereas `matplotlib` seems to accept continuous variables for x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seaborn's `barplot` is a categorical plot. This means it places the bars at successive integer positions (0,1,...N-1). Hence, if you have N bars, the axis will range from -0.5 to N-0.5.

There is no way to tell seaborn to place the bars at different positions; but you can of course fake the labels to let it appear as such. E.g. to label every 5th bar with the value from `x`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import ticker

sns.set()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(5, 10)
y = x ** 2

sns.barplot(x, y, ax=ax)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(np.arange(0, len(x), 5)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(x[::5]))
ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=90)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Inversely, it is possible to plot categorical plots with matplotlib. To this end, one needs to plot strings.

```
ax.bar(x.astype(str), y)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(np.arange(0, len(x), 5)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(x[::5]))
ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=90)
```

[image]

If you want a numerical bar plot, i.e. a plot where each bar is at the axis position of `x`, you would *need* to use matplotlib. This is the default case also shown in the question, where the bars range between 5 and 10. One should make sure to have the width of the bars smaller than the difference between successive x positions in this case.

```
ax.bar(x, y, width=np.diff(x).mean()*0.8)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=90)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's disappointing because I am trying to make a twinx plot of a lineplot and barplot with hue splits on both. It works with Matplotlib but I guess I'll have to implement hue on that myself